# Stunnel does send received Emails

Tags: email, gmail, imap, pop3, stunnel

I'm trying to use stunnel to encrypt Emails and send them to a Gmail or Outlook accout, I've activated POP3/and IMAP clients. But when I run the program I get the following error message:

[image]

I've double checked the firewall and the sending, but still don't undestand the issue here! 
does any here knows how may I solve this ?
thanks in advance ! 
**Update**

By the way I've try a dummy Mail, using [smtp4dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev) and it worked, so  I guess that the problem is on the stunnel side. 
here is the config file :

```
    ; Sample stunnel configuration file for Win32 by Michal Trojnara 2002-2017
; Some options used here may be inadequate for your particular configuration
; This sample file does *not* represent stunnel.conf defaults
; Please consult the manual for detailed description of available options

; **************************************************************************
; * Global options                                                         *
; **************************************************************************

; Debugging stuff (may be useful for troubleshooting)
;debug = info
;output = stunnel.log

; Enable FIPS 140-2 mode if needed for compliance
;fips = yes

; Microsoft CryptoAPI engine allows for authentication with private keys
; stored in the Windows certificate store
; Each section using this feature also needs the "engineId = capi" option
;engine = capi

; The pkcs11 engine allows for authentication with cryptographic
; keys isolated in a hardware or software token
; MODULE_PATH specifies the path to the pkcs11 module shared library,
; e.g. softhsm2.dll or opensc-pkcs11.so
; Each section using this feature also needs the "engineId = pkcs11" option
;engine = pkcs11
;engineCtrl = MODULE_PATH:softhsm2.dll
;engineCtrl = PIN:1234

; **************************************************************************
; * Service defaults may also be specified in individual service sections  *
; **************************************************************************

; Enable support for the insecure SSLv3 protocol
;options = -NO_SSLv3

; These options provide additional security at some performance degradation
;options = SINGLE_ECDH_USE
;options = SINGLE_DH_USE

; **************************************************************************
; * Include all configuration file fragments from the specified folder     *
; **************************************************************************

;include = conf.d

; **************************************************************************
; * Service definitions (at least one service has to be defined)           *
; **************************************************************************

; ***************************************** Example TLS client mode services

[gmail-pop3]
client = yes
accept = 111
connect = pop.gmail.com:995
verifyChain = yes
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
checkHost = pop.gmail.com
OCSPaia = yes

[gmail-imap]
client = yes
accept = 143
connect = imap.gmail.com:993
verifyChain = yes
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
checkHost = imap.gmail.com
OCSPaia = yes

[gmail-smtp]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:25
connect = smtp.gmail.com:465
verifyChain = yes
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
checkHost = smtp.gmail.com
OCSPaia = yes

[hotmail-pop3]
client = yes
accept = 110
connect = pop-mail.outlook.com:995
verifyChain = yes
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
checkHost = pop-mail.outlook.com
OCSPaia = yes
[hotmail-smtp]
client = yes
accept = 26
connect = smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
verifyChain = yes
CAfile = ca-certs.pem
checkHost = smtp-mail.outlook.com
OCSPaia = yes
protocol = smtp

; Encrypted HTTP proxy authenticated with a client certificate
; located in the Windows certificate store
;[example-proxy]
;client = yes
;accept = 127.0.0.1:8080
;connect = example.com:8443
;engineId = capi

; Encrypted HTTP proxy authenticated with a client certificate
; located in a cryptographic token
;[example-pkcs11]
;client = yes
;accept = 127.0.0.1:8080
;connect = example.com:8443
;engineId = pkcs11
;cert = pkcs11:token=MyToken;object=MyCert
;key = pkcs11:token=MyToken;object=MyKey

; ***************************************** Example TLS server mode services

;[pop3s]
;accept  = 995
;connect = 110
;cert = stunnel.pem

;[imaps]
;accept  = 993
;connect = 143
;cert = stunnel.pem

;[ssmtp]
;accept  = 465
;connect = 25
;cert = stunnel.pem

; TLS front-end to a web server
;[https]
;accept  = 443
;connect = 80
;cert = stunnel.pem
; "TIMEOUTclose = 0" is a workaround for a design flaw in Microsoft SChannel
; Microsoft implementations do not use TLS close-notify alert and thus they
; are vulnerable to truncation attacks
;TIMEOUTclose = 0

; Remote cmd.exe protected with PSK-authenticated TLS
; Create "secrets.txt" containing IDENTITY:KEY pairs
;[cmd]
;accept = 1337
;exec = c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
;execArgs = cmd.exe
;ciphers = PSK
;PSKsecrets = secrets.txt

; vim:ft=dosini
```

Comment: Please paste textual information as actual text, not a picture.

Comment: @Kamil thanks for replyin, I can't since it's a PLC that sending the Emai